# Run script using group policy

Tags: windows, group-policy, vbscript

I want to show an alert box to all users in the domain at regular intervals (example: show a message box on every 1 hour). How can i possible this using GPO. Already i know how to show log on script using GPO and vb script.

Comment: Use GPP and setup a new Task in the workstation Task Schedulers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would place the script on a network location all of the computers can access, and then use Group Policy to create a schedule task that runs every hour. [This article might help](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725745.aspx).